# Crashing application using Intents

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying to create an activity that has a button , clicking on which another activity starts.But when i run the app on android AVD it show an error "Unforunately your app has stopped".

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.myapp.SecondActivity.java"));
    }
}
```

And the second activity has the following code:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main >android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
    No Activity found to handle Intent
    { act=com.example.simpleapp.SecondActivity.java } 
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622) 
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417) 
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370) 
com.example.simpleapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:22) 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
```

I think i might be missing some statement ..... Please advise

Comment: Do you get that error when the app launches? Or when you touch the button?

Comment: You need to attach the output of your LogCat.

Comment: >FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.simpleapp.SecondActivity.java }
>android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
>android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
>android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
>com.example.simpleapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:22)
>android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>

Comment: @swayam i have pasted from log cat

Comment: Please bear in mind that the LogCat output is your best friend while debugging and it is easier for us to help you if you give the LogCat output. And also, put the LogCat in your question itself and not in comments. I will do it this time for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the **[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29)** :

> **`public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`**
>
> Create an intent for a specific component. All
>   other fields (action, data, type, class) are null, though they can be
>   modified later with explicit calls. This provides a convenient way to
>   create an intent that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name,
>   rather than relying on the system to find an appropriate class for
>   you; see setComponent(ComponentName) for more information on the
>   repercussions of this.

**`Parameters`**

```
packageContext
A Context of the application package implementing this class.

cls
The component class that is to be used for the intent.
```

### Code :

```
public void onClick(View view){
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Also see if you declared the activity in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: >android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.simpleapp.SecondActivity.java }

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed AndroidManifest.xml?
Write Log here, please.
You have to add activity into manifest file.

Comment: 06-11 14:20:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-11 14:20:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(870): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.simpleapp.SecondActivity.java } 06-11 14:20:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(870): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
06-11 14:20:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-11 14:20:43.575: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)

Comment: Try to write com.example.simpleapp.SecondActivity instead of com.example.simpleapp.SecondActivity.java